# Did Smith & Tinker and Pirahna Games' MechWarrior 5 title fall through?

Tags: mechwarrior

In July of last year [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/news_index.php?story=24360) did an article on a new MechWarrior title.  I haven't heard anything since.  Did the title fall through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly there were [legal troubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MechWarrior_%28reboot%29#Legal_troubles) (also [IGN](http://uk.xbox360.ign.com/articles/102/1021437p1.html)) regarding unseen designs and i didn't hear from any developments since - Harmony Gold strikes again. Most notably it seems as if Piranha still have not found a publisher and they have still listed it as *"in development"*.

I hope they make it through, from what i've seen it looks like it could be on par with the MW2 titles.

---

Update: This project has become [Mechwarrior Online](http://mwomercs.com/), a F2P online game.
Until its release, an alternative is [Mechwarrior: Living Legends](http://mechlivinglegends.net) (a total conversion for Crysis Wars).

Comment: Another Mechwarrior game in development is [Mechwarrior Tactics](http://www.mwtactics.com), an interpretation of the Battletech board game.